# Do Data Movement across the nodes happens during the Reducer Phase? MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

This is a Conceptual question. When the Mapper Functions Completes it emits Intermediate Key value Pairs on the  Local node.  If suppose The Jobtracker chooses reducer to run from different node, do the Data movement happens across the nodes?

If So , please let me know will the reduce Phase starts Only after all the Mapper Phase gets complete. Or will there be any background process that runs as soon as individual mapper gets completes, which will move/copy the data to the Reducer node?

Pl ignore if this question silly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If suppose The Jobtracker chooses reducer to run from different node, do the Data movement happens across the nodes?

Yes, if the `Reduce`task is running on a different node than the data movement happens across nodes.

> please let me know will the reduce Phase starts Only after all the Mapper Phase gets complete.

`Reduce` task it self will not be initialized until all the `Mapper`'s have completed. But the map tasks may finish at different times, so `Reduce` task starts copying `Mapper`'s data as soon as each map completes.This is called as `copy` phase of the reduce task. Once all the mappers gets completed processing and once all the data has been aggregated at the reducer side then the reduce method gets initialized.

> will there be any background process that runs as soon as individual mapper gets completes, which will move/copy the data to the Reducer node?

Mapper's intermediate data is served by an internal jetty web server hosted by the TaskTracker and the reduce task has set of threads that will copy the data from map output's in parallel specified by `mapred.reduce.parallel.copies`.